# How to get atomic clock with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create JavaScript countdown, but I have to use atomic clock (non local PC time).
I find the http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now, which gets you a JSON.

There is a property **currentFileTime** (timestamp), but not UNIX timestamp.

How to convert this timestamp to UNIX timestamp, get the Date Object and check Date, Hours, Minutes and Seconds?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need an atomic clock for a countdown? It's true you don't want to use local PC time, because that can skew or be set manually. Instead you generally want an increasing timer, such as `performance.now()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: hi Adam, the javascript `Date` object contains many useful methods - I believe what you are looking for is included - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. Take a look at the `parse` function.

Comment: The timestamp is coming from a .Net DateTime and represents the number of 100 nanosecond ticks since 0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001 - see the [.Net docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8) for more info

Comment: @Wazner If it is supposed to be a countdown to, say, October 12th, 08:00 UTC, then you do need a server-side clock if you want this to be unaffected by a local clock drift. (OTOH, with practically all computers on the network these days setting their time automatically -- and the countdown probably not needing sub-second precision, is this really a problem?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pick a timezone and call that:

With a call to `http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London.json`

You will get a json object with a unix time like here:

```
let result = {"week_number":29,"utc_offset":"+01:00","utc_datetime":"2019-07-15T11:44:07.720355+00:00","unixtime":1563191047,"timezone":"Europe/London","raw_offset":0,"dst_until":"2019-10-27T01:00:00+00:00","dst_offset":3600,"dst_from":"2019-03-31T01:00:00+00:00","dst":true,"day_of_year":196,"day_of_week":1,"datetime":"2019-07-15T12:44:07.720355+01:00","client_ip":"194.153.217.248","abbreviation":"BST"}

// result["unixtime"] => 1563191047
```

Comment: Thanks, is there worldtimeapi.org API documentation?

Comment: But FILETIME (Windows) to UNIX timestamp here: http://balrob.blogspot.com/2014/04/windows-filetime-to-javascript-date.html

Comment: They have a FAQ, where you can get some information: http://worldtimeapi.org/pages/faqs. Other than that I don't know. Also, why use `fileTime`, when you already have a JavaScript compatible time with just a different URL. @AdamŘezníček

Comment: But, is there alternative to Worldtimeapi.org with HTTPS protocol?

Comment: I honestly don't know.

Comment: Ok, Worldtimeapi.org has experimental HTTPS, but Worldclockapi.org not.